# Read array inside snapshot in Firebase with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Need help trying to read an array of this form:

[image: Firebase db]

As far as I tried, I got this

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let userUuid = defaults.string(forKey: defaultsKeys.keyOne)
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("images").child("\(userUuid!)")
let filterQuery = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "uuid").queryEqual(toValue: "\(uuid)") // where uuid is a value from another view

filterQuery.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for images in snapshot.children {
            print(images)
        }
})
```

But I receive nothing. I want to read the images' links to show them in the view controller.

Comment: Please post your Firebase structure as text, not an image. That way, we don't have to retype it and it's searchable. Do not use arrays! They are very situational and there are also alternatives that are much more flexible. Also, the images returned in snapshot.children are not images - they would be each parent node with all of the children (images, name, style etc).

Comment: Can you share any other flexible solution to read or save images by record?

Comment: For sure! When you post your Firebase Structure as text, we can further examine the issue and solutions.

Comment: Do you want it in json? Because I have that structure from firebase web, is there an option to copy it as text?

Comment: In the Firebase console, select your database, then in the upper right corner of the database area that are three vertical dots, click and select export JSON.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure that the `uuid` var in the line below is not an optional value (or if it is, unwrap it) because otherwise you'll be querying to compare to `"Optional(myUuidValue)"` instead of `"myUuidValue"`

   ```
   let filterQuery = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "uuid").queryEqual(toValue: "\(uuid)")
   ```
2. The `snapshot` in the line below contains more than just the images, it has all the other children under that uuid

   ```
   filterQuery.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in })
   ```

   So extract the images like this:

   ```
   filterQuery.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let retrievedDict = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
        let innerDict = retrievedDict["KeyHere"] as! NSDictionary  // the key is the second inner child from images (3172FDE4-...)
        let imagesOuterArray = userDict["images"] as! NSArray
        for i in 0 ..< imagesOuterArray.count {
              let innerArray = imagesOuterArray[i] as! NSArray

              for image in innerArray {
                   print(image as! String)
              }
        }
   })
   ```

   Clarification: cast all the children of the uuid as an `NSDictionary`, then extract the nested arrays using those two for-loops

**Update**
Thanks to Jay for pointing out the error! Also, as Jay suggested, consider restructuring your database and replacing those arrays with dictionaries that perhaps contain the URL, path (for deleting purposes if you need that), and timestamp of each image.

Comment: I am fairly confident this code won't work (actually I tried it). There are a couple of issues. One is that the retrievedDict variable contains a key value pair with a key of 3172... and a value of another dictionary. So the next line imagesOuterArray fails as there is no key of 'images' at that point. Most importantly though is to avoid using arrays in Firebase as they cannot be modified with insert, remove etc and the elements cannot be individually accessed. (also note the code isn't very Swifty with the use of NSArray and NSDictionary). With a  couple of tweaks though, it would work!

Comment: I agree actually about the usage of arrays in Firebase, but the structure in the OP's question has arrays so I was strictly sticking to it. But I have to disagree with you on the NSArray/NSDictionary part. Firebase's [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) clearly states the types for setting and retrieving objects. It wouldn't make much difference for NSArray and Array, but Dictionary needs a type initializer (`Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Bool>>` for instance), which would be a pain. Thanks for pointing out the error though I'll fix it shortly!

Comment: You simple define it as [String: AnyObject], and yes, their documentation is lagging behind a bit.

Comment: Oh well it's practically the same since you'd have to cast the AnyObject to possibly another dictionary. But you're certainly right about your way being more Swifty! I guess reading their docs got me used to using NSDictionary that way without really thinking about it. Thanks for your remarks! I honestly appreciate the constructive criticism! :)

Answer (score -1):

After strugling for the answer, got this code works

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("images").child("\(userUuid!)")
    let filterQuery = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "identifier").queryEqual(toValue: "\(identifier)")

    filterQuery.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            if (child as AnyObject).hasChild("images") {
                let images = (images as AnyObject).childSnapshot(forPath: "images").value! as! NSArray
                for i in images {
                    for j in i as! [AnyObject] {
                        let url = NSURL(string: j as! String)
                        //Then downloaded the images to show on view
                        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                            if error != nil {
                                print(error)
                                return
                            }
                            //Code to show images..

                        }).resume()
                    }


                }
            }
        }

    })
```

Can i receive feedback about this?